# Auto-Increment Id in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

In Sql we have auto increment which increase the value by 1 when we add any new row. I would like to have same functionality in elastic search.

Whenever I insert any document, there should be a corresponding field in index which holds the incremented data and it should be updated automatically.

Is it possible in elastic search ?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch cannot do this for you, so you'd need to manage that in your code